# What is a reporting framework?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

Reading on [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) and it says:

> The unittest unit testing framework was originally inspired by JUnit and has a similar flavor as major unit testing frameworks in other languages. It supports test automation, sharing of setup and shutdown code for tests, aggregation of tests into collections, and independence of the tests from the **reporting framework**.

*(emphasis is mine)*

I of course googled 'What is a reporting framework' expecting a SO question and didn't see one.  So, SO, what is a reporting framework in this context?

Answer (score 1):

The reporting framework is the part of the test system responsible for *reporting* the results of the tests. When you [run a test](https://ideone.com/NWQJDU):

```
import unittest

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_good(self):
        pass
    def test_bad(self):
        self.assertTrue(False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

and see output:

```
F.
======================================================================
FAIL: test_bad (__main__.MyTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 7, in test_bad
AssertionError: False is not true

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

the reporting framework takes the raw data about passes, failures, and exceptions, and produces the output you see.

`unittest` separates this from the part of the system directly responsible for testing functionality and the part of the system responsible for collecting and running tests. Running a `TestCase` produces a [`TestResult`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestResult) that the reporting system can use to determine what to report, without the reporting system needing to know how to actually test things. The reporting code can be customized or replaced without rewriting the test code.